# Subject lines using send_templated_mail

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm attempting to fix a bug in some legacy django code and am not an expert by any stretch so I was hoping someone could help with this little conundrum.

I have a views.py that states the following (note: user is an existing object):

```py
if user.is_eligible:
    email_template = 'subfolder/registered'
else:
    if form.cleaned_data['occupation'] == '1':  # media workers
        email_template = 'ideas/registered-template1'
    elif form.cleaned_data['occupation'] == '2':
        email_template = 'subfolder/registered-template2'
    else:
        email_template = 'subfolder/registered-template3'

send_templated_mail(email_template, None, recipient_list=[{'email': user.email, 'name': user.get_full_name()},], context={'name': user.given_name, })
```

and my template is as follows(ish)

```
{% extends 'templated_email/subfolder/base.email' %}
{% load waffle_tags %}

{% block subject %}Thank you for registering{% endblock %}

{% block header_image %}header.jpg{% endblock %}

{% block plain_body %}
Thank you for registering!

Congratulations.
{% endblock %}

{% block html_body %}
<p style="margin:12px 0;">
    <font face="Verdana,Arial,sans-serif" color="#595959" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 16px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;">Thank you for registering!<br/></font>
</p>
<p style="margin:12px 0;">
    <font face="Verdana,Arial,sans-serif" color="#595959" style="font-size:12px; line-height: 16px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;">Congratulations<br/></font>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The issue that I have is that, although the template comes through just fine and correct, the subject line comes through as the name of the template, but not for all of them.

I have tried replacing the dashes with underscores (so `subfolder/registered_template3.email`).

Anyone have anything they can suggest to try please?

Thanks
Obie

Comment: Please include the `send_templated_mail` function.

Comment: oh it's not a standard function?

Comment: the import statement is `from templated_email import send_templated_mail` but I can't find the origin so I think it's a library

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue.

in `common.py` (settings) the subject was being written like this:

```
TEMPLATED_EMAIL_MANDRILL = {
    '_default': {
        'auto_html': None,
        'auto_text': None,
        'from_email': 'return@address.com',
        'from_name': 'Reply Name',
        'google_analytics_campaign': 'email@address.com',
        'google_analytics_domains': ['email@address.com'],
        'headers': {'Reply-To': 'return@address.com'},
        'important': False,
        'inline_css': None,
        'metadata': {'website': 'www.mysite.com'},
        'return_path_domain': None,
        'signing_domain': None,
        'track_clicks': None,
        'track_opens': None,
        'tracking_domain': None,
        'url_strip_qs': None,
        'view_content_link': None,
    },
    'subfolder/registered': {
        'subject': 'My subject line',
        'from_name': 'Me'
    },
    'subfolder/registered_template1': {
        'subject': 'My subject line',
        'from_name': 'Me'
    },
    'subfolder/registered_template2': {
        'subject': 'My subject line',
        'from_name': 'Me'
    },
    'subfolder/registered_template3': {
        'subject': 'My subject line',
        'from_name': 'Me'
    },
}
```

(rendering the `{% block subject %}` in the template useless)

Adding the ones that were missing (and rendering the subject line incorrectly) fixed the problem.

Thankyou for looking anyway :)